# complex collection in java

Tags: java, collections

I need to define a collection of user defined objects with the following access methods:

1. access by the object's primary key (unique)
2. access by index of the collection sorted on a secondary key (not unique)

Each object has a primary key and a secondary key (not guaranteed unique).  When an object is added to the collection it should be inserted at a position so that the secondary key value is sorted.
Each object should be extracted or deleted using either the primary key or the position in the collection.

What is the best way to implement this collection?
(a map of the primary key and object would provide half of the access, and a sorted list would provide the other half.  How can these be combined for my requirement?)

Comment: Build a class that encapsulates the map and the collection?

Comment: *What is the best way to implement this collection?* Start coding. Otherwise, there never will be a `Collection` fitting your needs =)

Comment: "a map of the primary key and object would provide half of the access, and a sorted list would provide the other half. How can these be combined for my requirement?"  Why is having both of them as one object a requirement?  This sounds like a _solution._

Comment: Have you looked at Java collections that implement `SortedMap`?

Comment: what are complexity requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily write such a collention by yourself, where you have a (plain) `HashMap` of just primary keys to values, and then another one of a `PriorityQueue` of pairs of secondary keys to primary keys (seeing as secondary keys are not always unique, so you can't use a `Map` type for that).

## Solution:

Here is a full, working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MyCollection<T, TPrimaryKey, TSecondaryKey extends Comparable<TSecondaryKey>> {
    private HashMap<TPrimaryKey, T> primaryKeyMap;
    private List<PrimarySecondaryKeyPair> primarySecondaryKeyList;

    public MyCollection() {
        primaryKeyMap = new HashMap<TPrimaryKey, T>();
        primarySecondaryKeyList = new ArrayList<PrimarySecondaryKeyPair>();
    }

    public MyCollection(int initialCapacity) {
        primaryKeyMap = new HashMap<TPrimaryKey, T>(initialCapacity);
        primarySecondaryKeyList = new ArrayList<PrimarySecondaryKeyPair>(initialCapacity);
    }

    private class PrimarySecondaryKeyPair implements Comparable<PrimarySecondaryKeyPair> {
        public TPrimaryKey primaryKey;
        public TSecondaryKey secondaryKey;

        public PrimarySecondaryKeyPair(TPrimaryKey primaryKey, TSecondaryKey secondaryKey) {
            this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
            this.secondaryKey = secondaryKey;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(MyCollection<T, TPrimaryKey, TSecondaryKey>.PrimarySecondaryKeyPair o) {
            return secondaryKey.compareTo(o.secondaryKey);
        }
    }

    public void put(T object, TPrimaryKey primaryKey, TSecondaryKey secondaryKey) { // put by primaryKey
        primaryKeyMap.put(primaryKey, object);
        PrimarySecondaryKeyPair keyPair = new PrimarySecondaryKeyPair(primaryKey, secondaryKey);
        int insertionPoint = Collections.binarySearch(primarySecondaryKeyList, keyPair);
        primarySecondaryKeyList.add((insertionPoint > -1) ? insertionPoint : (-insertionPoint) - 1, keyPair);
    }

    public T getByPrimaryKey(TPrimaryKey primaryKey) {
        return primaryKeyMap.get(primaryKey);
    }

    public T getByIndex(int index) {
        return getByPrimaryKey(primarySecondaryKeyList.get(index).primaryKey);
    }

    public void deleteByPrimaryKey(TPrimaryKey primaryKey) {
        primaryKeyMap.remove(primaryKey);
        for (int i = 0; i < primarySecondaryKeyList.size(); i++) {
            if (primarySecondaryKeyList.get(i).primaryKey.equals(primaryKey)) {
                primarySecondaryKeyList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteByIndex(int index) {
        primaryKeyMap.remove(primarySecondaryKeyList.remove(index).primaryKey);
    }
}
```

This class (I think) does what you want and it doesn't store anything extra unnecessarily.

### Time complexity:

- `O(log n)` time for `put()` (in order to sort by secondary key).
  From the JavaDoc on the [`Collections.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method that this uses:

  > This method runs in `log(n)` time for a "random access" list (which provides near-constant-time positional access).

  <sup>(`primarySecondaryKeyList` is a "random access" list because it uses `ArrayList`).</sup>
- An average `O(1)` time for getting objects by the primary key (worst-case becomes `O(n)` if your primary key type has a *really* bad hash function).
  <sup>(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)</sup>
- An average `O(1)` time for getting by index sorted by secondary key, because that is based off of getting the primary key (this has to be done unless you want to store every object in the collection twice, which would take up twice the space).
- Constant `O(1)` time for deleting by index sorted by secondary key.
- `O(n)` worst-case for deleting by primary key (deleteing from primary key map is easy, but the secondary-to-primary key list has to be iterated over)

However, note that the worst case `O(n)` will never happen if your primary key is simply an `Integer` or a `Long`, because their hash functions are simply their numerical value, making them extremely good accurate (generally resulting in `O(1)` time for `get()`s).

### Usage:

The following examples assume that you are**storing `String`s** with **`Long`s as primary keys**, and with **`Integer`s as secondary keys**. The class is generic, however, so you can store any type of object with any type of primary key (just make sure it has a decent `hashCode()` function!) and any secondary key that is `Comparable` to itself (all the primitive `Number` wrappers, like `Integer`, `Long`, `Short`, etc. are already `Comparable` to themselves).

**To initialize with default initial capacity:**

```
MyCollection<String, Long, Integer> myCollection = new MyCollection<String, Long, Integer>();
```

**Initial capacity of 50:**

```
MyCollection<String, Long, Integer> myCollection = new MyCollection<String, Long, Integer>(50);
```

**Put the string `"hello"` with primary key `937234L` and secondary key `2`:**

```
myCollection.put("hello", 937234L, 2);
```

... everything else should be self explanatory ;)

---

That should meet the requirements and the type of collection you wanted.
Hope it helped. :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It is complete, is provided as a generic class and has an explanation of its performance and operation.

Comment: I thought I had logged in but the 'tick' was not there, so I could not 'accept' the answer. I have now logged in again and done so.

Answer (score 1):

> (a map of the primary key and object would provide half of the access, and a sorted list would provide the other half. How can these be combined for my requirement?)

```
public class YourCollection{
   private Map<UserObject> yourMap;
   private List<UserObject> yourList;

   public void add(UserObject obj){
      yourMap.put(obj.primaryKey, obj);
      yourList.add(obj);
      //sort list on secondaryKey
   }

   public UserObject get(String key){
      return yourMap.get(key);
   }

   public UserObject get(int index){
      return yourList.get(index);
   }
}
```

This is just the basic shell, but the idea is there. Which type of List and which type of Map you choose is up to you. You could/should also add generics to this class.

Edit- Also, there is no *best* approach to a given problem. You have to consider the pros and cons of different approaches and weigh them against your goals. For example, do you need this to take up the least amount of memory? Do you need it to use the least amount of CPU cycles? Do you need it to be the easiest code to write and maintain? Or are you just trying to put something together that works? I'm not actually asking you to answer those questions, but you should be considering them when thinking about this type of problem.

Comment: This is certainly a good starting point and worth investigating for any additional methods required.  If I am deleting an object by its key, I would have to search through the list to identify the correct object to delete from the list.  Is there a 'quick' way to do this?

Comment: @DonaldAshton Remove it from the Map first, which returns the Object. Then remove the Object from the List.